# Otsu thresholding method

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

Hi All and Happy New Year
I am writing my matlab code for otsu method but I have errors, If someone can look at my code and suggest me some corrections, I will be very grateful.
This is my code:

---

```
im1=imread('cameraman.tif');
%im1=rgb2gray(im1);
[n,m]=size(im1);
hst=imhist(im1);
mu=0;
N=0;
for i=1:255
    N=N+hst(i);
end
% The total mean level of the original image
for i=1:255
    mu(i)=mu(i)+((i.*hst(i))./N);
end


for T=1:254
    qb=0;
    muT=0;
    qo=0;
    for i=1:T
        qb=qb+(hst(i)./N); % probability of class occurence (background)
        m=m+((i.*hst(i))./N);% probability of class mean (background)
    end
    for i=T+1:255
        qo=qo+(hst(i)./N);% probability of class occurence (object)
    end
    sigma(T)=((mu-(qb*muT))^2)/(qb*qo)
end
[Y,T] = max(sigma)

[n,m]=size(im1);
for i=1:n
    for j=1:m
        if im1(i,j)>T
            im(i,j)=1;
        else
            im(i,j)=0;
        end
    end
end
figure(1);
subplot(1,3,1);
imshow(im1);
subplot(1,3,2);
imhist(im1);
subplot(1,3,3);
imshow(im);
```

---

thanks in advance

Comment: I'd recommend specifying what your errors look like. That is very helpful.

Comment: thank you Jamis I found my error and I post the entire code to help someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed two lines that induced errors, please test:

`mu=zeros(255,1);` instead of `mu=0;`

`sigma(T)=((mu(T)-(qb*muT))^2)/(qb*qo);` instead of `sigma(T)=((mu-(qb*muT))^2)/(qb*qo);`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you lennon310 for your help I just found my error
This my code hope that it helps some one else :

```
clc
clear all
close all
im1=imread('cameraman.tif');
%im1=rgb2gray(im1);
[n,m]=size(im1);
hst=imhist(im1);
m=0;
mu=0;
N=0;
for i=1:255

end
% The total mean level of the original image
for i=1:255
    N=N+hst(i);
    m=m+(i.*hst(i));
end
mu=m/N;

for T=1:254
    qb=0;
    muT=0;
    qo=0;
    mT=0;
    shis=0;
for i=1:T
    qb=qb+hst(i) % probability of class occurence (background)
    mT=mT+(i.*hst(i));% probability of class mean (background)
end
muT=mT/N;
qb=qb/N;
for i=T+1:255
    qo=qo+hst(i);% probability of class occurence (object)
end
qo=qo/N;
sigma(T)=(((mu*qb)-muT))^2/(qb*qo)
end
[Y,T] = max(sigma)

[n,m]=size(im1);
for i=1:n
    for j=1:m
    if im1(i,j)>T
        im(i,j)=1;
    else
        im(i,j)=0;
    end
end
end
figure(1);
subplot(1,3,1);
imshow(im1);
subplot(1,3,2);
imhist(im1);
subplot(1,3,3);
imshow(im);
```